# Reverse IP lookup resolves to old domain

Tags: dns

A site I administer recently rebranded under a new domain name. I updated the DNS to forward the old to the new, but reverse IP lookups are still resolving to the old domain. I don't see anywhere in my DNS settings where this could be a problem. Will this take longer than a regular DNS update or is there something else I can do to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The reverse DNS isn't usually set on your server but by the host datacentre that manages your server. When I setup a new server I usually send a message to the support saying, "Please set reverse DNS for host.example.com to 123.123.123.123 and please remove reverse DNS for old.example.com."

Comment: Thanks! For those of you who got here with the same problem and you are hosting with Rackspace, the reverse IP lookup is on the 'DNS' tab (duh!) of your server...I never thought to check here as I thought the problem was with a DNS server.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way round: "Please set reverse DNS for 123.123.123.123 to host.example.com ..."?